# Viewing copulating animals

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, animals, sexuality

As a child at the zoo I was taught that one is not allowed to view animals while they are copulating. However as a pet owner I have learned that the exposed genitals of animals do not prohibit a person from reciting a blessing or learning torah. I would like to know if it is in fact true that a person may not watch animals fornicate and what the source of this prohibition is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rambam, [Laws of Prohibitions on Relations, 21:19](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/5121.htm) (or #20, depending on your edition):

> וכן אסור לאדם שיקשה עצמו לדעת, או יביא עצמו לידי הרהור ...
>    ולא יסתכל בבהמה חיה ועוף, בשעה שמזדקקין זכר לנקבה; ומותר למרביעי בהמה להכניס כמכחול בשפופרת, מפני שהן עסקין במלאכתן ולא יבואו לידי הרהור.‏
>
> A man should not bring himself to arousal ... [gives a few examples] ... and similarly he should not stare at animals while they are mating. Professional breeders, however, are busy focusing on their work and this causes no arousal for them; hence they are even allowed to directly couple their livestock.

So it's not *erva* per se, it's "avoid the suggestive."

([As the commentaries point out](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=101037&rid=4519), Rambam is codifying Gemaras from Avoda Zara 20 and Bava Metzia 91.)