# "Siri, sing to me" - Kol Isha?

Tags: halacha, technology, kol-isha

As i say in [this Purim Torah answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55508/what-is-the-torah-preferred-brand-of-cell-phone/55660#55660), we can't use smartphones because "The vaad found out that Siri's not a guy". (From the song [Hang Up the Payphone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YL0K9eJinVE) by A.K.A Pella.)

However, that inspired a Siri-ous (groan) question.

According to answers to [Are men allowed to listen to women on the radio?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44297), some hold that it is forbidden to listen to women on the radio (and presumably recorded as well), due to the prohibition of "kol isha" (a man hearing a woman's voice).

**But what about something like Siri, which is computer-generated female-sounding speech synthesis?**

While hearing a woman simply speak is obviously permissible, it is possible to get Siri to sing by telling it "sing to me" (though the only song it knows is *If I Only had a Brain*, which it "sings" quite tunelessly).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27206

Comment: Siri is computer generated? I thought it was some woman from north carolina?

Comment: Sorry she's from georgia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susan_Bennett

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/49029/759

Comment: Well she's not singing so it wouldn't be an issue. Do you mean a computer generated women singing?

Comment: @andrewmh20 I said as much in the last sentence.

Comment: @Cnsersmoit my mistake. So then my response is- I think you can here even a real women simply speak.

Comment: I honestly don't know if it is against halachah, but you can actually change Siri's voice to be a man's.

Comment: +1. But -1 for the pun (siriously). So now it's even.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27206/759

Answer (score 5):

The reason we are not allowed to hear  woman sing is Because "kol isha airva" (The voice of a woman is nakedness) a womans singing voice is considered a part of her nakedness. It is forbidden to listen to a woman (besides your wife) sing out of fear that it will bring us to think about the woman singing. That's why many hold radio is ok, and Rav Elyashiv had to include "even if he knows the singer" in his heter. The gemara is clear that when one never sees the woman there is no issur.

In this case no singer exists. The voice of Siri can no more be considered "airva", than an iphone with out a cover would be considered naked.

Comment: Shaffier welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for your first answer! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). MY places a lot of emphasis on sources (after all most of us don’t know you personally). Maybe you will be interested by something I wrote to help you understand the site ["A beginner’s guide to MY - How is this site different from other Judaism sites”](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501)
 ?
I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Answer (score 2):

In the new print of the Yabia Omer 1:siman 6 footnote 9 he writes that Rav Eliyashiv mattired (allowed) one from hearing kol isha from the radio even if the person recognizes the singer,since the voice isn't real rather it is sound waves from the electricity. This opinion is quoted in שו"ת ישיב משה טורצקי  pg.14. The footnote also notes the מהרש"ג חלק ג סימן זה אות ב. I believe the Bnei Banim addresses this issue as well.

It must be noted that all would agree that if one would have sinful thoughts because of listening to the music then it would be prohibited entirely.

So if one would listen to SiRi sing which is an electric generated sound and one wouldn't have impure thoughts than it would be mutar. For halacha lmaaseh,ask your own Rabbi

Comment: "if one would have sinful thoughts because of listening to the music" The same would apply if someone has sinful thoughts from anything, eg. listening to a man tapping his fingers on yellow ceramic soup bowls.

Comment: See as well Yabia Omer 9:108:43

Comment: I know ,I am not arguing that point ,just felt I must note that

Answer (score -1):

Considering the reason a man is not allowed to listen to a woman sing is because of hirhurim, If a computer generated voice sounds so much like a woman that it brings you to hirhurim...Asur (because of the hirhurim)

Comment: Look at the comments on the OP, especially @doubleAA's link. Just because something SOUNDS like a woman doesn't make it assur. Castrattos/falsetto boys were popular substitutes for women singers, historically. You're not really answering the question, which does not include a discussion of hirhurim. Unless you are implying that as the only rubric in halachah? In which case, you're wrong.