# listening to a cappela during sefira?

Tags: halacha, music, mourning-aveilus, provenance, sefirat-ha-omer

A friend of mine told me that there is a problem with listening to a cappela during sefira. A few people mentioned a few places where it talks about it but I don't remember the places. What is the source for this?

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1050/13811
And https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82038/13811

Comment: By the second link if you go to where you source your answer from it says there at the end rav miller says a cappela is asur (the link there isn't working for me so I'm not sure exactly what he says) so is it a machlokes so to speak "who do you follow"

Comment: @mmc99 Yes, it appears to be a machlokes. Your question seemed to ask for the source of the reason why it might be assur, so those links hopefully provided you with that information.

Comment: Can you define a cappella? Do you mean listening to people singing, like at a Shabbat table?

Comment: I was told there is a difference between shabbos and the rest of the week but yes along the lines of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Leket Yosher](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8859&pgnum=97) (quoted in Piskei Teshuvot 493:35) writes that his teacher (the *[Terumas Hadeshen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Isserlein)*, about whose *[minhagim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minhag)* the entire sefer is about) did not sing *zemiros* on *motzaei shabbos* during the days of *sefira*, except when Lag Baomer came out on sunday.

Comment: implying that the rest of the week for sure not if even motzaei shabbos not?

Comment: @mmc99 Obviously. *Motzaei shabbos* is just the same as any day in the week. The implication from this is that on shabbos itself it's permitted.

Answer (score 0):

[Matzav](http://matzav.com/p%E2%80%99sak-from-rav-yisroel-belsky-and-rav-shlomo-miller-on-acappella-music-during-sefirah/) has a Psak from Rabbi Yisroel Belsky differentiating if it is a choir or a Capella. A choir (without music) is permitted and a Capella which sounds like music would be prohibited.

Comment: it also says there that rav miller doesn't allow it I'm looking for a answer with sources